# C++: how can I get the list of folders

Tags: c++, linux

I am not familiar with C++ as I am a C# developer.

In my project, I need to delete all folders of one week before. In C++, how can I get the list of the folders of one week before based on the current system date time?

I am working on Eclipse IDE running on Ubuntu 10.10.

If you could provide some sample of code, that would be great.

Thanks in advance and your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Any particular platform?

Comment: There's no platform-independent way of getting filesystem meta-information, so you'll need to specify a platform...

Comment: @Kornel: Well, not without using a library (like Boost!) that hides all the platform-dependence from you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With boost:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main(int, char**)
{
    time_t one_week_ago = std::time(NULL) - (7 * 24 * 3600);

    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator dir("/tmp"), end;

    BOOST_FOREACH(const boost::filesystem::path& p, std::make_pair(dir, end))
        if(boost::filesystem::is_directory(p))
            if(boost::filesystem::last_write_time(p) < one_week_ago)
                boost::filesystem::remove_all(p);
}
```

or without using boost::foreach

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main(int, char**)
{
    time_t one_week_ago = std::time(NULL) - (7 * 24 * 3600);

    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator dir("/tmp"), it, end;

    for(it = dir; it != end; it++)
    {
        const boost::filesystem::path& p = *it;
        if(boost::filesystem::is_directory(p))
            if(boost::filesystem::last_write_time(p) < one_week_ago)
                boost::filesystem::remove_all(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi chris,Thanks for your example, could you please help me to rewrite it as for() statement instead of foreach()? as in the requirement, the foreach library is not included :( the filesystem library from boost is installed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `std::remove_copy_if` to create a copy of the list of directories, skiping the newer directories. Then, use `std::for_each` to remove the remaining, older directories.

Answer (score 4):

It's more a question of your OS API than C++. C++ itself provides no facilities for filesystem operations. However, there are several portable libraries that do, [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html) for example.

However, if you're stuck only to one operating system, it's easier to use it's facilities -- POSIX on *nixes, or WinAPI on Windows.

Both are C based, to get a C++ solution, you need a third party library.

On Linux, the following might get you started:

- [File Access and Directory System Calls](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node20.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought you should look at the functions opendir and readdir - also look at stat.
Basically, open the top level directory, and examine all entries in it that are directories.
The stat function will be able to give you access and modify times.